# show that $x^3 = (1234)$ in $S_7$ has three solutions (and find them?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

As title. This is question 52 in Chapter 5 of Gallian’s Abstract Algebra, 10th edition. My current line of logic is as follows.

We have $x^3 = (1234)$, which gives us $|x^3| = 4$, implying that $|x| = 12$. In $S_7$ there is only one orientation of $n-$cycles that has lengths with an lcm of 12, and that is $(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)(a_5 a_6 a_7)$. This works out, since we can have

$$(x)^3 = (\text{some rearrangement of 1, 2, 3, 4})^3(a_5 a_6 a_7)^3 = (\text{some rearrangement of 1, 2, 3, 4})^3 $$

My question, is how we get this correct rearrangement, and where do these three solutions come from, and what are they?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $|x^3|=4,\ |x^2|=12$ ? Is it the order ?

Comment: Same issue [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/345472/305862)

Comment: Let $\alpha+(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$. Then $\alpha\alpha^{-1}=1=\alpha^4=(\alpha^4)^{-1}=(\alpha^{-1})^4=(\alpha^{-1})^3\alpha^{-1}$, so $\alpha=(\alpha^{-1})^3$.

Comment: Well $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)^4=(1)$ so $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)^9=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$ so one solution is $x=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)^3$. Another one is $x=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)^3(5\ 7\ 6)$.

Comment: By the way, $|x^3|=4$ does not imply $|x|=12$.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4455914/permutation-groups-find-x-such-that-x5-12345) for solving such a question.

Comment: In my earlier comment, the plus sign should be an equals sign.